# Mysql Sort Split Character String

Tags: mysql, string, sorting, split

I have the following table, say, MyDRAW

```
DRAWNO   PRIZENO
A123/14  8458
```

I managed to use SUBSTRING function to spli the PRIZENO into 4 character, 8 4 5 8

```
SUBSTRING(PRIZENO, 1, 1) AS FIRSTNo,
SUBSTRING(PRIZENO, 2, 1) AS SECONDNo,
SUBSTRING(PRIZENO, 3, 1) AS THIRDNo,
SUBSTRING(PRIZENO, 2, 1) AS FOURTHNo,
```

But, My Question is how to sort this number into their order ASC, for example: 4 5 8 8

Therefore, after the sorting, my Select result can be as follows:

```
DRAWNO  PRIZENO FIRSTNo SECONDNo THIRDNo FOURTHNO SORTED1 SORTED2 SORTED3 SORTED4
A123/14 8458    8       4        5       8        4       5       8       8
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to sort or concating the digits to a full number again?

Comment: I want to have PRIZENO (in full), split PRIZENo (As Original) and Split PRIZENo (Sorted)

Comment: Anyone can help? I wonder STRCMP function can help out with IF function. Still think on this

Answer (score 0):

No Choice, and I am not sure whether there are any good / better way ...

I did like this ...

```
CONCAT(
IF(SUBSTRING(PRIZENO, 1, 1)=0,"0",""),
IF(SUBSTRING(PRIZENO, 2, 1)=0,"0",""),
IF(SUBSTRING(PRIZENO, 3, 1)=0,"0",""),
IF(SUBSTRING(PRIZENO, 4, 1)=0,"0",""),
IF(SUBSTRING(PRIZENO, 1, 1)=1,"1",""),
IF(SUBSTRING(PRIZENO, 2, 1)=1,"1",""),
IF(SUBSTRING(PRIZENO, 3, 1)=1,"1",""),
IF(SUBSTRING(PRIZENO, 4, 1)=1,"1",""),
IF(SUBSTRING(PRIZENO, 1, 1)=2,"2",""),
IF(SUBSTRING(PRIZENO, 2, 1)=2,"2",""),
IF(SUBSTRING(PRIZENO, 3, 1)=2,"2",""),
IF(SUBSTRING(PRIZENO, 4, 1)=2,"2",""),
IF(SUBSTRING(PRIZENO, 1, 1)=3,"3",""),
IF(SUBSTRING(PRIZENO, 2, 1)=3,"3",""),
IF(SUBSTRING(PRIZENO, 3, 1)=3,"3",""),
IF(SUBSTRING(PRIZENO, 4, 1)=3,"3",""),
IF(SUBSTRING(PRIZENO, 1, 1)=4,"4",""),
IF(SUBSTRING(PRIZENO, 2, 1)=4,"4",""),
IF(SUBSTRING(PRIZENO, 3, 1)=4,"4",""),
IF(SUBSTRING(PRIZENO, 4, 1)=4,"4",""),
IF(SUBSTRING(PRIZENO, 1, 1)=5,"5",""),
IF(SUBSTRING(PRIZENO, 2, 1)=5,"5",""),
IF(SUBSTRING(PRIZENO, 3, 1)=5,"5",""),
IF(SUBSTRING(PRIZENO, 4, 1)=5,"5",""),
IF(SUBSTRING(PRIZENO, 1, 1)=6,"6",""),
IF(SUBSTRING(PRIZENO, 2, 1)=6,"6",""),
IF(SUBSTRING(PRIZENO, 3, 1)=6,"6",""),
IF(SUBSTRING(PRIZENO, 4, 1)=6,"6",""),
IF(SUBSTRING(PRIZENO, 1, 1)=7,"7",""),
IF(SUBSTRING(PRIZENO, 2, 1)=7,"7",""),
IF(SUBSTRING(PRIZENO, 3, 1)=7,"7",""),
IF(SUBSTRING(PRIZENO, 4, 1)=7,"7",""),
IF(SUBSTRING(PRIZENO, 1, 1)=8,"8",""),
IF(SUBSTRING(PRIZENO, 2, 1)=8,"8",""),
IF(SUBSTRING(PRIZENO, 3, 1)=8,"8",""),
IF(SUBSTRING(PRIZENO, 4, 1)=8,"8",""),
IF(SUBSTRING(PRIZENO, 1, 1)=9,"9",""),
IF(SUBSTRING(PRIZENO, 2, 1)=9,"9",""),
IF(SUBSTRING(PRIZENO, 3, 1)=9,"9",""),
IF(SUBSTRING(PRIZENO, 4, 1)=9,"9","")) AS CON1,
```